# how to extract time format from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract time from this string `"Last Updated on Jul 9 2019, 3:15 pm +08"`

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
var str = "Last Updated on Jul 9 2019, 3:15 pm +08";

  var result = str.match(???);
    if(result) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
</script>
```

or is it possible to extract the date and time but in array form like `['Jul 9 2019','3:15pm']`

I'm new to using regular expression and have no idea how to formulate the pattern. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your desired output of `[{'Jul 9 2019'},{'3:15pm'}]` is not even valid syntax in Javascript.

Comment: You can just take a sub string, if the string always starts with `Last Updated on `. Otherwise, there is no way of doing this with a simple regex.

Comment: sorry, it should be array object i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind to find 'on' in the string, grab everything up to the pm/am, and split on the comma and space, assuming the format is consistent:

```js
const str = "Last Updated on Jul 9 2019, 3:15 pm +08"
console.log(str.match(/(?<=on ).*(p|a)m/)[0].split(', '))
```

> Note, the positive lookbehind feature is not compatible with all browsers, so I would recommend using [adiga's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948057/10445697) approach if compatibility is an issue.

Comment: No problem. If you ever need more help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex `/on ([^,]+),\s*(.*(?:am|pm))/` with one capturing for date and another for time

```js
var str = "Last Updated on Jul 9 2019, 3:15 pm +08";
var result = str.match(/on ([^,]+),\s*(.*(?:am|pm))/);
result.shift();

console.log(result)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4ZB2v/1)

Comment: thank you this is very useful answer same with the first one

Comment: You could use `var [, ...result]` here instead of shift, so you don't have to write another line :P

Comment: @Kobe Yeah but, OP is using `var`. So, didn't want to make it confusing by adding destructuring

Comment: Yeah, I understand, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using regex (assuming that the format of the time remains same like in the example you gave). Like this:

```js
var str = "Last Updated on Jul 9 2019, 3:15 pm +08";
var onlyTime = []
onlyTime.push(str.split(' ').slice(3,6).join(' ').slice(0, -1));
onlyTime.push(str.split(' ').slice(6,8).join(''));
console.log(onlyTime)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you what use regular expression you can use '\d{1,2}:\d{2} (am|pm)' for find the time into the string of date. With \d{1,2} you have the digit between 1 and 60, with (am|pm) you find string 'am' OR string 'pm'.